# Bigquery streaming API returns "unsupported content with type"

Tags: java, google-bigquery

We're using bigquery streaming API.

Trying the operation below via java client, I am getting "unsupported content with type: application/json; charset=UTF-8".

But trying the same operation via APIs exploler, it works well.

I can't find my mistake.

```
POST /upload/bigquery/v2/projects/foo/datasets/bar/tables/baz/insertAll HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer xxxx
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_45
Host: www.googleapis.com
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 62

{"ignoreUnknownValues": true,"rows":[{"json": {"id":"xxx"}}]}
```

Comment: I found the url is wrong. the correct is : "POST /bigquery/v2/projects/foo/datasets/bar/tables/baz/insertAll"

Comment: Do you mind posting this as an answer? :) that way other people with a similar issue will be able to see it faster that it's actually fixed and proper :)

Answer (score 0):

The URL for your request is not properly formed for an InsertAll.

You're using 
POST /upload/bigquery/v2/projects/foo/datasets/bar/tables/baz/insertAll

When the proper url should be  POST /bigquery/v2/projects/foo/datasets/bar/tables/baz/insertAll